# How should I test functions that call other functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

```py
def task_completed(task: Task) -> None:
  _update_status(task, TaskStatus.COMPLETED)
  _process_task(task)


def task_canceled(task: Task) -> None:
  _update_status(task, TaskStatus.CANCELED)
  _process_task(task)

# ...

def _process_task(task: Task) -> None:
  send_notification(task)  # already tested
  cleanup(task)  # already tested
```

I have written tests for the "public" functions `send_notification` and `cleanup`. Since I defined `_process_task` as a "private" function I don't write a test for this one.

How should I write tests for the functions:
`task_completed` and `task_canceled`

Both functions are calling the `_process_task` function which calls the functions `send_notification` and `cleanup` which I've already tested.

Should I just test if these two "public" functions are called or should I test everything again what theses two functions are actually doing?

Comment: If you've already tested the "other functions", I wouldn't test them again unless your new tests fail and you have reason to suspect they are the culprits (which would call into question how well you tested them on their own).

Comment: IMHO the `_update_status` and `_process_task ` functions should be mocked, you have to test only what concerns on your test function (`task_completed` for example) so it would be better to check only the flow of that function work correctly and the parameters are passed as expected

Comment: The functions `send_notification` and `cleanup` - are they from the same component?

Comment: @DirkHerrmann The functions are from different components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions `task_completed`, `task_canceled` and also `_process_task` do not contain computations, only interactions.  Therefore, if any bugs are present in these functions it will be interaction bugs: Are you calling the right functions from the right component in the right order, with the right parameter values in the right order, and are the results provided as you expect them (return values / exceptions)?

Therefore, for the test of these functions, unit-testing does not have much value: Unit-testing is about finding the bugs that can be found in the isolated component.  Consequently, your functions should be tested in integration testing: This is where the abovementioned bugs can actually be found.  Thus, you should not duplicate testing what `send_notification` and `cleanup` are doing, but rather that they are called (in the right way).

An interesting aspect is about how to handle `_process_task` during these integration tests: If you take a black-box perspective during these tests, you would have to test twice that `send_notification` and `cleanup` are called correctly (from `task_completed` and from `task_canceled`).  If you take a glass-box perspective, you would only have to test that once.  Whether this makes sense depends on many aspects, and thus I would not discuss it here.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a "black box" test and simply test the behaviour of task_canceled and task_completed, without worrying of the internal behaviour.